# Compare two hashtables using a Java function with OR/AND

Tags: java, function, compare, hashtable, operands

I want to compare the data in two different hashtables using two JAVA functions. One functions works on the basis of OR and returns all different data.
The second function works on AND and returns only the values present in both. Two tables will have a key identical in both

The Connection ID will be the key in both hashtables but both will contain different columns.

```
ConnectionId    Imei                Imsi    IsData  IsSignalling    IsVoice
330708186825281 99999006686069  999992223223602 FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
260339442647675 99999207564306  999993793410366 FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
260339442647676 99999605176135  999992216631694 FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
330708186825331 99999007880884  999992226681236 FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
330708186825354 99999002855874  999995430231562 FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
330708186825281 99999006686069  999992223223602 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
330708186825390 99999500436869  999992219841377 FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
260339442647737 99999307617391  999992223829327 FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
330708186825390 99999500436869  999992219841377 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
260339442647676 99999605176135  999992216631694 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
330708186825429 99999621055912  999992227382787 FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
260339442647791 99999507265228  999992225698840 FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
330708186825429 99999621055912  999992227382787 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
330708186825429 99999621055912  999992227382787 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
260339442647796 99999607648349  999992227489358 FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
260339442647791 99999507265228  999992225698840 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
260339442647796 99999607648349  999992227489358 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
260339442647675 99999207564306  999993793410366 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
330708186825354 99999002855874  999995430231562 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
260339442647811 99999208568534  999992228054917 FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
260339442647796 99999607648349  999992227489358 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
260339442647796 99999607648349  999992227489358 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
189970698469977 99999507405260  999992226504812 FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
189970698469977 99999507405260  999992226504812 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
189970698469977 99999507405260  999992226504812 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
```

I tried using a Map and and iterating through the entries but don't know how to work with operands

Comment: What is the value mapped to the key in that hash table? Is it a object? or?

Comment: Please explain what you mean with different columns. Are the columns the same but have different contents or are the columns not related?

Comment: Please clarify, you have 2 Java `Map` objects and want to perform logical operations on those `Map`s? Also what are the types of keys and values of those `Maps` ?

Comment: Lets say the Connection Id is key in both tables. One table will have Imei, IsData, IsSignalling and the other will have Imsi and Is Voice.

Comment: If I want to use an AND, then for Connection Id present in both, collate the data. Same for OR.